# escape doesn't fix python regex error: unbalanced parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I'm not very well versed in python, but from what I read on here, using re.escape() should fix the unbalanced parenthesis error. But it's not working for my code.

Can someone help explain this for me?

```
    data_name = get_results(re.search('^(?!<br>).*(?=<br>)', pdf_data.group(0)))
    data_name = re.escape(data_name)
```

example html output

```
    <span style="....">THING<br>ANOTHER TEXT THING<br></span>
```

main bit of my code:

```
    # this is the pattern of the entire main span
    text_pattern = '(?<=<span style="font-family: BALKHK+Arial,Bold; font-size:13px">(.*?)(?=<br></span></div>)'


    def get_title():
        # converted_html is the converted html file using pdfminer
        for pdf_data in re.finditer(text_pattern, converted_html, re.DOTALL):

            data_name = get_results(re.search('^(?!<br>).*(?=<br>)', pdf_data.group(0)))
            data_name = re.escape(data_name)

            test_list.append(data_name)

        return test_list
```

Comment: Is it html code you are parsing? Give the example input.

Comment: This is difficult to debug without seeing the error or the input.

Comment: yes it is html. I've edit the question with an example of the html. I'm trying to get the text "THING" (as a test)

Comment: What does `get_results` do? I don't get an unbalanced parenthesis error.

Comment: I think the error is not on these lines. Can you paste your full source code (on pastebin, for example) ? (Note that the `get_results` function can be reduced on one line : `return info.group(0) if info else ''`)

Comment: I updated the main parts of my code that deals with what I'm trying to do. Which is extract the text

Comment: `text_pattern` has unbalanced parenthesis ...

Comment: @B.V `text_pattern = '(?<=<span style="....">(.*?)(?=<br></span></div>)'` you're missing a close paren here

Comment: A closing parenthesis `)` is missing for Positive Lookbehind. It should be `(?<=<span style="....">)(.*?)(?=<br></span></div>)`

Comment: hmm, adding that close paren after the span gives another error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Comment: yes that's obvious. look-behind accepts only fixed-width pattern `+` `*` is somewhat not allowed.

Comment: @B.V I think you've made a typo then.

Comment: dot has special meaning in regex it should be escaped `(?<=<span style="\.\.\.\.">)(.*?)(?=<br></span></div>)`

Comment: @Braj only if it's actually a literal dot. OP could be correct that the style is any four character string.

Comment: @AdamSmith but as per the example its four literal dots.

Comment: no the dots are just to replace whatever I have in the span. Since I'm using pdfminer, it's just font-name: fontname; font-size etc. I'll add it if it helps solve this problem

Comment: @Braj frankly `....` often means `I left something out here because it's not important`. That combined with this question's general vagueness and need for clarification after clarification after clarification, I don't trust OP's exact text :)

Comment: @B.V if your ACTUAL text is more like `(?<=<span style="font-name=\w+"` then you're hosed. You cannot do variable-length lookbehinds in `re`. You can in `regex` (which is proposed as a replacement for `re` in a future version of Python) but that sounds like it may be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @B.V why don't you use an XML parser like `lxml` or its wrapper `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: @B.V ah ha, there's your issue. `font-family: BALKHK\+Areal,Bold` is necessary

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is almost always a very bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest using a parser rather than regex.

```
import bs4

txt = r'''<span style="....">THING<br>ANOTHER TEXT THING<br></span>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt)

for span in [span for span in soup('span') if span.attrs['style'] == '''font-family: BALKHK+Arial,Bold; font-size:13px''']:
    result = span.next_element
```